# My game not displaying ads after suspension of my old Admob account

Tags: admob, adsense

I had a game published on Google Play which I put admob ads on.

My admob account was disabled because of invalid click activity.

Now I made another account which I link my game to it.

My code for displaying ads is correct also I provided my adsense account with the right payment settings. In spite of previously mentioned my game shows no ads.

What can I do now ?

Answer (score 1):

If your account is disabled, ad serving is disabled to all apps in that account. You'll need to change the package name for your game if you haven't done so.

If you've changed your package name but ads still don't show, it could be there are no ads to serve. Check the log output. You can also check if ads fail to load.

Make sure you don't click your own ads. Always use test ads before publishing. You may also read the [admob behavioral policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en) to be on the safe side

Answer (score 0):

That app is black listed for admob, so you need to change package name and deploy again.or check AdSense appeal form